# How can i force a complete load in a webpage

Tags: google-chrome

I am sure many of you have seen sites that get loaded as you scroll down, for example in a manga/comic site, the resources (Images) gets loaded as you scroll down.

**What i am looking for is a force load for all these resources and images in one click** without having to scroll down, is this possible?, how can i achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the Lazy Loading feature

In Chrome navigate to `chrome://flags/` then set the option to Disable

[image]

Relaunch Chrome, and you're all set.

Comment: Lazy loading really seemed like the solution but i just tried it and it seems the pages still get loaded after i scroll, here is an example:  https://toomics.com/en/webtoon/detail/code/91793/ep/0/toon/4640 , Please note to confirm this you can use developer tools network tab

Comment: What about disabling lazy frame loading too?

Comment: Yes, even disabling Lazy frame is not effective, maybe something else is going on there?, maybe the images are loaded by code ?, try scrolling and look at the network tab, you can see that as you scroll down, the network tab loads the resources

Comment: I can confirm, this sounds exactly what needs to be fixed but the problem persists.

Comment: This switch will only affect browser-controller lazy loading. Website themselves can also do it using JavaScript, and that would be unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is impossible without writing a custom extension to modify the JS or without emulating a tall-screen device. Both serve one purpose: to make the website think that you've already reached an image, and serve it to you before you actually scroll own to it.

The sites that get loaded while you scroll down have got nothing to do with lazy loading, instead they use something called [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) that allows the site itself (and not just on behalf of your browser) request images in realtime without reloading. That's why you see these red loading spinners - if the images were lazily-loaded by the browser there would be just slowly appear. For example, [this giant (90 Meg!) Mona Lisa scan from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg) may serve as an illustration of how lazy-loading would look in your browser - an image slowly growing downwards, without any spinners.

This comic site, on the other hand, is just programmed not to load images unless you are looking at them. You could mitigate that by:

- Writing a bookmarklet or an extension in JS that modifies the loader script on the page and makes it serve everything to you as fast as it can.
- Using something like Firefox [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode), set width to your screen space and increase the height severely, then scroll the actual content (NOT SCREEN). The images should load before they enter your actual screen space.
- Getting a faster connection (this really is an option!). The images might load faster and you'll probably find it much less irritating.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've come with a workaround that works on mangamtl, haven't tried on other sites yet.

Try zooming out the webpage completely, scroll to the end and go back up. It seems when I do that it starts to load all the images.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP doesn't want to scroll.